# LyX bibliography problems

Tags: biblatex, lyx

I am using LyX 2.0.0.3. I am tyring to insert bibliography. I am using `plain` in the bibliography style and `article` as a document style. When I convert the document in the pdf, it shows heading "References" and then displays nothing.
How can I fix this?

Comment: See this link on [“Normal” use of BibTeX from LaTeX](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=usebibtex)

Comment: @PeterGrill: LyX will invoke `bibtex` implicitly if required. @user4299 (you might consider choosing a better name...): (1) Have you added at least one bibtex database (`.bib` file) in the "BibTex Bibliography" dialog? (2) Have you actually any citation in your document?

Comment: @Daniel: Removed comments.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments. I have solved this problem in another way. I just write the following command in the latex preamble

```
\usepackage{apacite}
```

and then everything work fine. I can change the bibliography style by adding the same command with package name.

Comment: For other users that came here with a similar problem it should be mentioned, though, that this solution is probably very specific for the setup of the OP. Usually, LyX's bibliography works "out of the box" without any hassles. If not so, take a look on my above comment first.